# Getting Error tokenizing data while reading multiple csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a ton of csv's and want to merge them into on single df

```
tmp = [] 

for file in directory_liste:
    df_x = pd.read_csv(file,sep=';')
    tmp.append(df_x)

df = pd.concat(tmp)
```

I get this Parser Error `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 119, saw 6`

when I try to read just a single file  `df = pd.read_csv(file,sep=';')` I get no error

Are there maybe some files with different format ? How can I find them

`"VarName" ; "TimeString"; "VarValue","Validity ", "Time_ms"` this is the format when I open the file in excel .

Comment: From the error, it seems one of your rows has more than five fields.

Comment: in all files or in just some files ?

Comment: log the file name to see on what file is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the file that caused the error

```
tmp = [] 

for file in directory_liste:
    try:
        df_x = pd.read_csv(file,sep=';')
        tmp.append(df_x)
    except pd.errors.ParserError:
        print(file)
```